# Redirect automatically any http error code

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-headers

I actually use this (for exemple) in my .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

And I repeat the line for each error code.
I was wondering if there's a way to redirect automatically any http error code and catch this error to reuse it dynamically.

Comment: nope. `ErrorDocument` doesn't accept wildcards, or multiple codes. you'd have to list every possible 3-digit code you want your script to handle, each in its own ErrorDocument.

Comment: I'm also looking for a non htaccess solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to use one `ErrorDocument` directive to catch all errors. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument

See also: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/custom-error.html

A non-htaccess solution may be to route *everything* through a script and have the script return the relevant error codes. However, this **will not** handle certain errors, like 50* errors that get thrown by the server which would bypass the running of your script.

Best solution is still to enumerate `ErrorDocument`s for each code.